# Is there a way to load link or script tags from a separate html file?

Tags: html

When writing web pages I often end up with a lot of script ot link tags in the head of each html file.
Something like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to consolidate this into one line that loads all of them from a separate file, something like this `<link rel="" href="libraries.html">`? Or maybe have one `<link>` that loads both other links? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css","//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial"`?

I looked into doing this with a `<link>` but I didn't see any obvious way.

Comment: In HTML? No there is not

Comment: If you linked to a JavaScript file, you could use a bunch of [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) statements.

Answer (score 0):

**Possibility:**

Adding script from another HTML file: No

Adding script from other Javascript File: Yes

---

**Syntax:** to load external JS:

```html
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Hope, It Helps.